# If $n$ is an integer and $3n+2$ is even, then $n$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am still new to proofs and just starting to get some practice in. Here is what the homework problem asks.

Prove that if $n$ is an integer and $3n+2$ is even, then $n$ is even.

Proof attempt by contradiction: Suppose $3n+2$ is even and $n$ is odd. If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $3n+2=3(2k+1)+2=2(3k)+5$. Since $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $3k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $3k=m \Rightarrow 3n+2=2m+5$, which is odd. Thus, contradicting our assumption that $3n+2$ is even. $\blacksquare$

I feel as if I am missing some steps and/or grazing over something important. Any feedback, tips/suggestions, or words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normally you use a known fact for your contradiction, not the premise. You didn't use your assumption anywhere. This is better framed as a proof by contrapositive.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response. How would I state it appropriately if I wanted to prove it by contradiction? Would I say, "assume $n$ is odd."?

Comment: Remove "Suppose..odd" and start with "Assume that $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$." at the end "Thus, contradicting the assumption that 3n+2 is even." The rest of the proof is fine.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proof is OK.

Say $n$ is odd, so $3n$ is odd, so $3n+2$ is odd, a contradiction.

---

Or you can do like this: since $2\mid 3n+2$ we have $2\mid (3n+2)-2 = 3n$. But $\gcd(3,2)=1$ so $2\mid n$.

Comment: Sorry, we haven't covered too much on gcd and the method you are suggesting. How can we assume $2$ divides $3n+2$?

Comment: Because $3n+2$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof by contradiction is fine. This is a direct proof: if $3n+2$ is even then there is $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $3n+2=2k$. Hence, since $n$ is an integer, it follows that 
$$n=2k-2-2n=2(\underbrace{k−1−n}_{\in \mathbb{Z} })$$ 
which means that $n$ is even.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand how you arrived at $2k-2$, but how do we get $-2n$? Sorry, if I am lacking on my algebra. It is a little late here.

Comment: We have that $3n+2=n+2n+2$ and then we move $2n+2$ to the other side.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a correct proof by contradiction, more simply we can conclude from here

$$2(3k)+5=2(3k)+4+1=2(3k+2)+1$$

but it is really a detail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I am happy to hear I am starting to get a little more comfortable with it.

Comment: Also, I was trying to do some algebra and manipulate it, but I couldn't figure it out. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

If $3n+2$ is even, then $3n+2\equiv0 \mod 2\Rightarrow 3n\equiv0 \mod 2$. 
Where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}=\{0,1\} $.

If $n\equiv1 \mod 2$ then $3(1)\equiv0 \mod 2$ this is a contradiction, since $1\not \equiv0 \mod 2$.

Therefore $n\equiv 0 \mod 2$ then $n$ is even.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We have not covered modulo ideas, yet, so I am having a little hard time understanding your solution.

Comment: Don't have problem, since  $a\equiv b \mod m \Leftrightarrow m\mid (a-b) \Leftrightarrow a-b=mq+r$, such that $0\leq r <m$ then $r\in \{0,1,2,\cdots, m-1 \}$